# Reecrever url com htaccess

Tags: htaccess

Por falta de experiência, estou tendo dificuldade em reescrever a url do meu blog, tentei conforme abaixo:

```
http://www.meusite.com/blog/article.php?a=3&v=5&at=teste-do-primeiro-post
```

No final gostaria do resultado abaixo:

```
http://www.meusite.com/blog/article/teste-do-primeiro-post
```

Coloquei o `.htaccess` na raiz e depois dentro da pasta blog, qual a pasta que o `.htaccess` tem que ficar?

Minha última tentativa abaixo:

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteRule ^article/([0-9]+)/([0-9a-zA-Z_-]+) article.php?a=$1&v=$1&at=$1 [NC,L]
```

Answer (score 0):

O problema está na expressão regular!

Por exemplo, vc está pegando números com a ER `([0-9]+)` no lugar onde viria `teste-do-primeiro-post`, que é uma sequência de caracteres.

De uma maneira geral, sem restrição a não ser a `/`, vc pode tentar o abaixo (coloquei mais uma variável at2 além das suas que recebe o resto da URL - até o final):

```
RewriteRule ^([^\/]*)\/?([^\/]*)\/?([^\/]*)\/?(.*)$ article.php?a=$1&v=$2&at=$3&at2=$4 [L,QSA]
```

Comment: Inseri na pasta principal do servidor deste jeito RewriteRule ^?([^\/]*)\/?([^\/]*)\/?([^\/]*)\/?(.*)$ article.php?a=$1&v=$2&at=$3 [L,QSA] e gerou o internal error 500

Comment: Você tem que inserir dentro da pasta "blog", onde contem a pasta article!

Comment: Inseri dentro da pasta blog, mas está retornando error 500

Comment: Removi o primeio `?` estava errado na resposta. Você pode tentar colocar o caminho na frente (após o `^`) ou tb utilizar o `RewriteBase /` ou `RewriteBase /blog/`